deepcopy fails with object that contains objects that contain sets that point to each other with __hash__
This MWE builds a Network class and a Node class. A Node has attributes called predecessors and successors, each of which is a set that will contain other Nodes. Functions in the two classes manage the structure of the network.
from copy import deepcopy

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = []

    def add_node(self, node):
        self.nodes.append(node)

    def add_successor(self, node, successor_node):
        node.add_successor(successor_node)
        successor_node.add_predecessor(node)
        self.add_node(successor_node)

class Node:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        self.predecessors = set()
        self.successors = set()

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.index

    def add_successor(self, successor):
        self.successors.add(successor)

    def add_predecessor(self, predecessor):
        self.predecessors.add(predecessor)

network = Network()
node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
network.add_node(node1)
network.add_successor(node1, node2)
deepcopy(network)

This code fails on the last line (deepcopy(network)) with the error:
  ... etc ...
  File "/path/to/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/path/to/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 264, in _reconstruct
    y = func(*args)
  File "/path/to/deepcopy_mwe.py", line 22, in __hash__
    return self.index
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'index'

If I do any one of the following things, the error goes away:

Replace the predecessors and successors attributes with lists instead of sets (initialize them to [] and use append() instead of add() in add_successor() and add_predecessor()).
Remove the line successor_node.add_predecessor(node) in Network.add_successor() (so that the nodes don't both point at each other).
Remove the __hash__() function.

What's going on here, and how can I fix it?

You should probably remove the __hash__ method in any case.  That's normally only used if you want two different instances of the class to compare as equal under certain conditions, but in that case you should also have a compare function that performs the desired comparison.  In this case, since the nodes are connected in a graph, such a comparison probably doesn't make much sense.

Why are you defining __hash__ on a mutable type?

Defining __hash__ not only makes no sense in this context, but it's also what's breaking deepcopy.  The problem: deepcopy first creates the object, without calling its __init__method, then attempts to populate its attributes.  If it ends up calling __hash__ in the process, before setting index, then you will get this error.  To make it work, you need to define your own __deepcopy__ method (which takes a memo argument that allows you handle references to other copied objects).  You'd also want to define a __copy__ method.  But don't do any of that.  Just remove __hash__.

I defined __hash__ because I want to be able to have sets of Node objects. My code does also have an __eq__ method (something like, return self.index == other.index) but I omitted this from my MWE. So in that case is my only option to implement __deepcopy__ and __copy__?

Actually I think a better approach is to use sets of indices, and convert those indices to Node objects when needed.

But @TomKarzes your explanation is good and if you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

If the Node index values are unique, and you want to keep sets of them, then you'd be much better offer keeping sets of the direct, integer index values.  You could then use a dict to map them onto nodes, e.g. d[i] = Node(i).  If the index values are not unique, then trying to keep a set of nodes probably doesn't make sense.  But having a __hash__ method of a mutable value is really just a bug.  It's very much the wrong way to solve your problem, and will create more additional problems than is solves (as you've already seen).

@TomKarzes Agree with all of that. My Node indices are unique, and I use the approach you're describing elsewhere in my code. I'll get rid of __hash__ and update accordingly. Thanks for your help.
